# Google Cloud - kubernete fail mount disk

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an issue with a Kubernetes in our google cloud account.
One of our sites stop working ( loading and saving data ), we check the Kubernetes and we saw this error message `Unschedulable Pods`.

We "fix" the problem by changing the number of nodes from 0 to 1 in the node `dedicated-pool`.

Now we have a problem to mount the storage (prometheus-xxxxxxx) . The status is `ContainerCreating` and we have some failure events:

> FailedAttachVolume ( Count 65 )
>   AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-de40c835-82ca-11e7-9f6d-xxxxxxxx" : GCE persistent disk not found: diskName="gke-cluster-1f-6802d39-pvc-de40c835-82ca-11e7-9f6d-42010a800072" zone="us-central1-f"
>
> FailedMount ( Count 51 )
>   Unable to mount volumes for pod "prometheus-2768782531-nvs4d_default(4c576673-7664-11e9-b063-xxxxxx)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"prometheus-2768782531-nvs4d". list of unmounted volumes=[gke-prometheus-storage]. list of unattached volumes=[gke-prometheus-storage config-volume default-token-skgu9]

Any help will be appreciated !! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the documentation https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#PodUnschedulable "PodUnschedulable indicates that your Pod cannot be scheduled because of insufficient resources or some configuration error". To avoid such errors in future I'd recommend you to follow best practices  https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits.

Comment: There're lots of possibilities cause error with persistent disk (1. persistent disk in the other zone 2. you didn't create the actual storage before you define the PV an so on). Please update your question with deployment steps and your configuration files (yaml).